# Created New Rails App, Unable to launch on Heroku and receiving errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Created a new rails 5 app, only have one controller for static pages, and am trying to push it to Heroku to start. I am not sure what is causing the error on heroku. Can't find any concrete information. What could be causing the issue?

The Heroku Logs

```
2017-06-02T02:10:53.461595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-hamlet-31215.herokuapp.com request_id=e9e76236-08c3-4ae7-a6a8-35edf8897476 fwd="162.200.138.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-02T02:10:54.766544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-hamlet-31215.herokuapp.com request_id=9ff158f8-0816-4c8b-b754-3d86a0000bc2 fwd="162.200.138.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Heroku Rails Console

```
Running rails console on ⬢ nameless-hamlet-31215... up, run.9398 (Free)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

Gem File

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Please share your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Added as requested

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things:

1. Try restarting the app, if it works..hurray!
2. since it is a pg error, try running rake commands*

   rake db:create

   rake db:setup

   rake db:reset

   rake db:migrate

*Don't run them all at once, run one and check if error message goes/changes.

3. Lastly, comment the `pg` gem and `bundle` and push again.

Hope it helps..

**Update:**

I just realized, did you add *heroku postgres* addon to your app? Go to your dashboard and add it if not.

Comment: I tried all the mentioned above and its still not working, same error messages